# Limit a user to VI and Tail

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, user, restrictions

I'm running a server on centos 6.0 and I'm looking for a way to limit ssh access of one user to only tail and vi and only in their home folder.
I found some guidelines to the home folder part but haven't found tips on the tail & vi part.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to [chroot their SSH session](https://superuser.com/search?q=ssh+chroot), and only put `tail` and `vi` in the chroot.

It can also be done with SELinux, but this is a much more complex route, requiring you to define a number of SELinux objects to account for the different actions required by logging in and such.